# Can you what Apple ID is now associated with my MacBook Air using its serial number?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud

My MacBook Air was stolen. Can you see what Apple ID is now associated with my MacBook Air using its serial number?

Comment: What does it help if you know the Apple ID?

Comment: it would be a privacy nightmare if it were possible

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to lookup that information for ordinary customers.

Apple has access to the information, but you cannot just call them and expect them to be able or willing to tell you. They would probably require an official request from the police with a warrant or similar.